# Shower leaking after renovation - grout/caulk question

Tags: shower, leak, grout, caulk

The place I rent recently had a bathroom renovation done due to long term shower body leaks (as well as some other leaking). Long story short, they put up Durock and re-tiled everything. My question is, shouldn't there be caulk surrounding the entire area where the tub meets the tiles? The tub is a bit of an odd setup. The wall at the foot of the tub is the entryway to the bathroom where the doorway is. The wall at the head of the tub where the shower head is installed is a kind of partition wall with the toilet on the other side of it. I'm not sure if I'm explaining that correctly so I'll include some pictures.

[image: zoomed out shower and wall]

The contractors put new molding and caulk where the molding meets the tub. They also put caulk where the molding meets the tiles vertically.

[image: shower side and wall]

However, they didn't put any caulk anywhere else the tile meets the tub. When I took a shower, there were giant puddles on the floor on *both* sides of the partition wall, leading me to believe the water is getting inside and funneling downward, leaking out the bottom. I guess my question is, should there be caulk around the entire tub? Particularly around this region here. I think this may be where the water is escaping. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: possible source of leak]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tub has a flange around the 3 sides against walls.   The tile overlaps that flange about 3/4" or so. This makes it harder for water to past the tub edge.

It is better to have caulk that matches the color of the tile along the bottom of the tiles, but grouting done well should block water as well.

You can turn on the shower and close the curtain, to watch where the water is coming from. It may be just getting past the curtain and running over the edge of the tub.  There may also be a leak in the piping to the shower arm and water is leaking in the wall and coming out onto the floor.  Another possibility is the water is seeping between the tile and the flange and escaping past the flange end near the front of the tub.

This needs more investigation. However as a tenant it should not be your responsibility to discover the source of the water.

Comment: Landlord responsibilities aside, I'm looking for the right way to have this done.

The puddles appeared to be two separate ones. The shower body was repaired/replaced and tested, so I don't think (hopefully) it's from there. It's possible the water only got in on one spot and just kind of split into two puddles because of the way the water was channeled down. Not sure. I would say it's very likely it's getting passed the flange though. 

And agreed, I know it shouldn't be my responsibility but I also don't want to go through the hell that was this renovation again if there is a leak.

Comment: I did another test. I think you're right about it slipping past the curtains! The shower head is dripping. The drops fall on the bottom spigot. Then the water builds up, travels to the wall and falls down onto the lip of the tub. Over time, the water builds up more and started traveling down the lip towards the front of the tub, then right through the gap in the curtains and over the side, pooling along the ground, where it eventually creates what looked like two puddles on either side.

Comment: Sometimes a pair of corner guards can help.  Something like these:  https://www.build.com/product/summary/1382490?uid=3259466&jmtest=gg-gbav2_3259466&inv2=1&&&&&&source=gg-gba-pla_3259466!c6970300949!a75187317730!dc!ng&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAu9yqBhBmEiwAHTx5pwL6uM4izVuW8hj86wWsjHEdFKb_cpv3BOeQEdnEYk2WyLdsLS4g0BoCY4oQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: I'll have to look into that. I know I had them years ago but water just seemed to pool up and then go around them